# Coffeescript postfix operator with else

Tags: coffeescript

I'm trying to write things as nice and semantic as possible, but I am running into an issue where I'm not sure how to express myself succinctly. I was doing the following in a callback in node:

```
    res.send(500, { error: err }) if err?
    res.send(resource) if resource?
    res.send 404
    return
```

However, I throw header already sent errors all over the place... Ideally I want to do something like:

```
    res.send(500, { error: err }) if err? else
        res.send(resource) if resource? else
            res.send 404
    return
```

or

```
   res.send(500, { error: err }) if err?
   else res.send(resource) if resource?
   else res.send 404
```

Where I can keep things succinct and easy to follow. Sadly, this causes the compiler to explode. So as a result, unfortunately I'm stuck with stuff like:

```
    if err?
        res.send 500, error: err
    else 
        if resource
            res.send resource
        else
            res.send 404
```

Which doesn't feel that coffee to me, I almost might as well be writing normal javascript.

So I'd appreciate anyone who can help me figure out a nice way to do logic trees like this in a prettier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what you're doing. Ultimately, your goal is to *send something* according to a cascade of rules: Error, Success, or Not Found. Coffeescriptly, I'd end up writing:

```
res.send.apply null, if err then [500, {error: err}] else if resource then [resource] else [404]
```

Which, admittedly, is a little long, but that's what we have IDEs for.

[Edit]

```
r = if err then [500, {error: err}] else if resource then [resource] else [404]
res.send.apply null, r
```

There, now both lines are less than 80 characters.

Comment: I don't like that it exceeds any reasonable maximum line length. Other than that it's reasonable.